# How to use Phonegap to display directory inside sdcard

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am building an android base Phonegap application using ionic framework, may i know how to display all the SD card files directory using Phonegap? I used Phonegap file API and i try somthing like this http://www.digitalnoiz.com/mobile-development/mobile-file-explorer-with-phonegapcordova-and-jquery-mobile-part-1/, however i found out that i am actually accessing my root directory and my phone haven't root yet, i see no file in the screen. Alert message says that i am inside root directory but no file displayed, i think it is because i have no permission to my root file. The display screen will be blank, may i know how can i fix this problem? Instead of accessing my root directory, i want to get my external SD card file. Or other than the cordova file api matter, any other ways that i can display my sdcard file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using mfilechooser plugin? - `[https://github.com/Langstra/MFileChooser][1]`

You can access all files in external or Internal storage

```
window.plugins.mfilechooser.open([], function (uri) {

      alert(uri);

    }, function (error) {

        alert(error);

    });
```